# Programmable stand alone Button (hardware+software)

Tags: vb.net, hardware, usb, serial-port

I need to have a physical button that when pressed will be noticed by my program.
There are many types of usb-buttons that are preprogrammed to open a website, shutdown the computer and so on. And I have seen some projects using buttons and serial port.

But none of them "have it all", an easy description of how to put togheter the hardware, and an easy description of the code.

I really only need a button connected to the serial port that send some signal that the button has been pressed.

I know this question is a crossover between software and hardware, but when I googled this I have seen plenty more people asking this question, all of them left without answers.

Maybe this question fits stackoverflow?

**EDIT: My solution**

My application in this case was a que system and I wanted a button for people to print a que ticket.

I just took apart an old ps2-mouse and bought me a button (4$) and solded two wires from the circuit board to the button. Each mouse button has to dots on the back of the circuit board that we can connect an external button to.

Then in my program I just hooked the mousebutton-event systemwide to get when the button is pressed, in my case this computer is dedicated to this program so its not a problem.

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking for the same thing. this might do the trick:

http://awatts.co.uk/

Haven't tried it yet, but he has code to run a shell command or simulate a keypress and the source code is available if you need something different.

And for Linux: search freshmeat dot net for usb-panic-button-daemon project. (I'm a new user, and can't post more than one hyperlink!)

And another thing I just found is that Griffin makes an SDK available (at least they used to, I'm waiting for a reply) for their PowerMate knob to get it to simulate more than mostly just keypresses.

BTW I'm looking for USB buttons, but I could use serial too, come to think of it.

Answer (score 3):

Might be worth a look at Phidgets:

http://www.phidgets.com/index.php

They do many little USB I/O devices, and the code samples are there on the site too.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at the [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) microcontroller board - you can wire all sorts of things into that (buttons, sensors) and interface with it using the .NET Ports classes.

Comment: I have seen that site before. And although it sure has what I want, there is no specifik information about what I need for my problem. I dont want to learn everything about microcontrollers, just solve the one button problem. So if there are a place that describes how to use that microcontroller board to send info to computer when a button is pressed then its what I want. But thanks anyway.